# How to write Google test for ternary variable?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googlemock

I am checking the some configurations conditions to return the type values. This is the piece of function code.

```
typdef enum{
    type1 = 0,
    type2,
    type3,
    type4,
    type5
}

#define config  (uint8) ((type1_enble()) ? (type1) :
    (((type2_enable())? (type2) :
    ((type3_enable())? (type3):
    (type4_enable())?(type4):(type5)))))

int process_input(void)
{
    int result = type1;
    
    if( (config == type1) || (config == type2) )
    {
        result = type1;
    }
    else if(config == type3)
    {
        result = type3;
    }
    else
    {
        /**/
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now i would like to test the function code using google test.

//This are the input set

```
make_tuple(0,0,0,0)
make_tuple(0,1,0,0)
make_tuple(0,0,1,0)
make_tuple(0,0,0,1)
make_tuple(1,1,1,1)
```

//Test code

```
TEST_P(test_config , test1)
{
    ON_CALL(mock, type1_enble()).WillByDefault(input1);
    ON_CALL(mock, type2_enble()).WillByDefault(input2);
    ON_CALL(mock, type3_enble()).WillByDefault(input3);
    ON_CALL(mock, type4_enble()).WillByDefault(input4);
    process_input();
}
```

But here i don't know how to make full the coverage of the code. Especially the ternary variable. I am not getting 100% code coverage when i run the test case. Any problem here especially the ternary variable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time the `config` macro is expanded, every branch of that compound expression is injected into the code, which means that there's around 125 different code paths through that function.

So to get full coverage of the function as written, you'd need to go over all permutations of `typex_enble()` for repeated invocations. i.e. you need to account for `type1_enble()` returning 0 on the first invocation, and 1 on the second.

If repeated calls to `typex_enble()` always return the same value, then you should just evaluate the expression once:

```
int process_input(void)
{
    auto cfg = config;
    int result = type1;
    
    if( (cfg == type1) || (cfg== type2) )
    // ...
```

Comment: How `auto cfg = config;` will help in this case ?

Comment: Because `config` is only evaluated once then, so you have 5 paths, instead of 5*5*5

Comment: Yes !! I agree. Thanks for the info

Comment: As often, MACRO is bad. Regular function would be ok too.